# How we can Varnish support using Lando for drupal8 recipe

Tags: lando

How we can Varnish support using Lando, I am using default .lando.yml file

```
name: d8
recipe: drupal8
config:
  php: '7.2'
  webroot: web
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add any other support provided by lando using service:

```
name: d8
recipe: drupal 8
config:
  php: 7.2
  webroot: web
services:
  varnishcache:
    type: varnish:4.1
    backends:
      - appserver
    backend_port: 80
    ssl: false
    config:
      vcl: config/custom.vcl
```